# How to make the TLS work in MQTT via port 8883?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I need help to configure this MQTT to work on **TLS** mode.
I have setup the MQTT in the server. The **server** is protected by **letsencrypt** certificate that's why it has **https** in its **domain**, then I set it up also in a remote computer.

the server runs this command

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t 'testtopic' -p 1883
```

the remote computer runs this command

```
mosquitto_pub -h domainName -t 'testtopic' -m "test message" -p 1883
```

the MQTT configuration on both computers is like this

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
port 1883
persistence_file mosquitto.db
log_dest syslog
log_dest stdout
log_dest topic
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous true
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

this one works. but how to make the communication into TLS mode?
can someone please let me know what's the proper configuration?
how to pass parameters in both computers?

- I have tried changing the port of the config into **8883**
- In both computers I have tried passing the **--cafile** whereby the cafile
  is a **.pem certificate** which came **from** the **server** which was **generated** **by letsencrypt**. So I just copied that and pasted it to the remote computer

those are the things I have tried so far, but in the wireshark it cannot detect TLS communication at all and the connection is being refused or something wrong with CA file

Comment: Edit the question to show how you have changed the broker configuration and exactly how you passed the `-cafile` option to `mosquitto_pub`and `mosqitto_sub`

Answer (score 5):

By setting `allow anonymous true`, anyone can publish to your broker without authentication.

TLS is not used directly in MQTT brokers, you need to configure MQTTS which uses TLS. 
To use a secure MQTT connection,your Mosquitto configuration file found in /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf needs to have the following lines:

```
listener 8883
cafile <path-to-cafile>
certfile <path-to-server-cert>
keyfile <path-to-server-key-file>
```

where `<path-to-cafile>`,  and  needs to be replaced by your absolute path where your ca file, server certificate i.e. your **.pem** file and server-key certificate is found.

For example in my case my mosquitto.conf looks like this:

```
    pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

    persistence true
    persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

    log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

    listener 1883
    protocol mqtt

    listener 8883
    cafile /etc/ssl/certs/broker/ca.pem
    certfile /etc/ssl/certs/broker/server.pem
    keyfile /etc/ssl/certs/broker/server-key.pem
    tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Save this configuration and restart mosquitto using the above configuration

You can test your TLS connection by running:

```
mosquitto_pub -t test -m test-message -p 8883 --cafile <path-to-your-ca-file> --insecure
```

In my case it is:

```
mosquitto_pub -t test -m test-message -p 8883 --cafile /etc/ssl/certs/broker/ca.pem --insecure
```

You need to use *--insecure* option because the certificates are all self-signed. Self-signed server certificates cannot be verified by the mosquitto client. 
If you don't use the *--insecure* option, you'll get an error which says

```
Error: host name verification failed.
OpenSSL Error: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

To setup authentication, create a text file with content

```
<user>:<password>
```

where  is a placeholder for the username you want to allow 
and  is a placeholder for the password you want to set

For example:

```
panda:black
```

will create a user called panda and the password for the user *panda* will be *black*.
To encrypt the password, run the command

```
mosquitto_passwd -U <path-to-passwordfile>
```

This will now have contents like this:

```
panda:$6$a2foLssTVgMG4QY6$3rWvoLqwo1uCz6jZH6KDK3yAcWtIFlATbOSbwx7XJx2Q5Mix2S+iRqWI7KDqp43nSDdPV7mMvnYJS6tgHb7QjA==
```

Now add these two lines to the mosquitto configuration file

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file <path-to-passwordfile>
```

Restart/reload the mosquitto broker to have a fully authenticated MQTTS connection

To publish to the broker with username and password use:

```
mosquitto_pub -t test -m test-message -p 8883 --cafile <path-to-ca-file> -u panda -P black --insecure
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turned out that mosquitto requires all three configuration options (`certfile`, `keyfile`, `cafile`) to be specified, see also [issue #1836](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1836). Also one can check if SSL is really enabled using `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8883` which should dump server certificate to the screen. If that is not working any client trying to initialte SSL will be reported as `Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error` to mosquitto log.